# Saving multiple child takes too much time (5 sec +)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

saving  table with multiple children takes too much time to execute (more than 5 sec)

tried this,

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

Timesheet Model

```
package com.Erp.Model.TimeSheetModel;

@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "timesheet")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = 
ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property="id", scope = 
Timesheet.class)
public class Timesheet extends BaseEntity{

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_personal_information_id")
private EmployeePersonalInformation employeePersonalInformation;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "timesheet_id")
private Collection<TimesheetBudget> timesheetBudget;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "timesheet_id")
private  Collection<TimesheetDateType> timesheetDateType;
}
```

TimesheetBudget Model

```
package com.Erp.Model.TimeSheetModel;

@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "timesheet_budget")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = 
ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property="id", scope = 
TimesheetBudget.class)
public class TimesheetBudget extends BaseEntity {

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "timesheet_budget_id")
private Collection<TimesheetHours> timesheetHours;  

@ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Timesheet timesheet;
}
```

TimesheetHours Model

```
package com.Erp.Model.TimeSheetModel;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "timesheet_hours")
public class TimesheetHours extends BaseEntity {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
@JsonIgnore
private TimesheetBudget timesheetBudget;
}
```

TimesheetDateType Model

```
package com.Erp.Model.TimeSheetModel;

@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name="timesheet_date_type")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = 
ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property="id", scope = 
TimesheetDateType.class)
public class TimesheetDateType extends BaseEntity {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Timesheet timesheet;    

}
```

Timesheet Service

```
package com.Erp.Service.TimeSheetService;

@Service
public class TimesheetService {

@Autowired
TimesheetRepository timesheetRepository;

public ResponseEntity<String> saveTimesheet(Timesheet timesheet) {
    timesheetRepository.save(timesheet);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Timesheet Saved Successfully.");
}   
}
```

Timesheet Repository

```
package com.Erp.Repository.TimesheetRepository;

@Repository
public interface TimesheetRepository extends JpaRepository<Timesheet, 
Integer>{

}
```

Comment: How many SQL statements is this executing? How long does each take? Please show the code how you construct/load the entities until you are committing/flushing your changes.

Comment: this is executing 252 JDBC statements  which takes 24271248 nanoseconds to prepare statements, 4264116140 nanoseconds to execute statements,  2157771785 nanoseconds to execute 1 flush and 15702 nanoseconds to acquire jdbc connection.